# Singular Value Decomposition to predict a missing value from an otherwise FULLY POPULATED matrix

Tags: matrix, prediction, svd

this is my first question, and I hope it's not misdirected/in the wrong place.

Let's say I have a matrix of data that is fully populated except for one value.  For example, Column 1 is Height, Column 2 is Weight, and Column 3 is Bench Press.  So I surveyed 20 people and got their height, weight, and bench press weight.  Now I have a 5'11 individual weighing 170 pounds, and would like to predict his/her bench press weight.  You could look at this as the matrix having a missing value, or you could look at it as wanting to predict a dependent variable given a vector of independent variables.  There are curve fitting approaches to this kind of problem, but I would like to know how to use the Singular Value Decomposition to answer this question.

I am aware of the Singular Value Decomposition as a means of predicting missing values, but virtually all the information I have found has been in relation to huge, highly sparse matrices, with respect to the [Netflix Prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netflix_Prize) and related problems.  I cannot figure out how to use SVD or a similar approach to predict a missing value from a small or medium sized, fully populated (except for one missing value) matrix.

A step-by-step algorithm for solving the example above using SVD would be very helpful to me.  Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths, not implementation. It belongs on http://maths.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I will post it there.

Answer (score 0):

I was planning this as a comment but its too long by a fair bit so I've submitted it as an answer.

My reading of SVD suggests to me that it is not very applicable to your example. In particular it seems that you would need to somehow assign some difficulty ranking to the bench-press column of your matrix, or some ability ranking of the individuals. Perhaps both. Since the amount he can bench-press depends solely on his own height and weight I don't think SVD would provide any optimization over just calculating the statistical average of what others in the list have accomplished and using that to predict the outcome for your 5'11 170lb lifter. Perhaps if there was BMI (body mass index) column and if BMI could be ranked... and probably a larger data set. I think the problem is that there is no noise in your matrix to be reduced by using SVD. Here's a tut that appears to use a similar problem: http://www.puffinwarellc.com/index.php/news-and-articles/articles/30-singular-value-decomposition-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, I read that article but didn't understand how to make a prediction from there.  I'm not sure what a statistical "average" would be when something is a function of two or more independent variables, but it is non-trivial to find the most similar rows and compute a prediction based on those.

Comment: you can find a group of people whose average height is 5'11 - find another group whose avg weight is 170lb, determine if there are any members of one that are also members of the other, and calculate their avg bench-press. if there aren't then id say you need a larger sampling. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: There should be a more direct method, whereby you calculate a modifier over the entire range of measurements, such that the relationship between (height and weight) and bench-press are condensed into a single formula (HW/M=B). I'm not sure how the data would correlate really since lying down on a bench and pressing a weight might have very little to do with height, or even weight. BMI might mean something, but height and weight don't seem to predict arm/chest strength very much. Time in training would be a much better predictor I think, but only because training increases muscle mass (BMI).

Comment: Well, I'm actually just using this as an example, and maybe it wasn't a very good one.  I'm more interested in understanding an SVD approach than answer this question - which I could easily do with a simple 3D surface fit.  A more complex example in banking would be, let's predict how likely a person is to default on their credit card debt given their annual income, credit score, amount borrowed, number of additional credit cards, and any number of other variables that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: then I would go back to that article and walk through it with the author, solving that problem. there are modifiers like player ability and hole difficulty that make all the difference in the world as to how applicable SVD is to the problem. Having done that you should be able to see what it will take to apply it to some other case - or at least which cases it should apply to.

Comment: actually the next example there correlates words to concepts in book titles and includes python code with a full explanation. Job done.